# how to force specified locale for specific route group/file Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, localization

lets assume i have a website 
`www.example.com`
and admin dashboard:
`www.example.com/admin/*`
i need to force locale language for all routes of `admin/` to english 
all admin routes located in `routes/admin.php`
what i have already tried:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:admin'], function() {

    App::setLocale( 'en');//**not working**
    app()->setLocale('en');//**not working**
    //other routes of admin

});
```

and tried this and also **not working**: in the `app/http/kernel.php`

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
   
    'admin' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\LocalizationAdmin::class,
    ],
];
```

where the `LocalizationAdmin` class is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class LocalizationAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $locale='en';

        app()->setLocale($locale);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should register in   protected $middleware

Comment: Clearing cache any time you change config or something? Good to have on back of mind is to execute `composer du && php artisan optimize:clear`.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your middleware function like this, you can set your app locale for all your routes that are admin in the first segment:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->segment(1) == 'admin') {
        app()->setLocale('en');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Remember to make sure you use the middleware for your related routes.

Answer (score 0):

First create new middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware AdminLocale
```

In the middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    app()->setLocale('en');
    return $next($request);
}
```

Register it `$routeMiddleware` (path `app/Http/Kernel.php`)

```
'adminLocale' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminLocale::class,
```

In the route group call

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'AdminLocale']], function () {
    // Admin routes
});
```